# What happened to my free space

Tags: disk-usage

On my *Amazing **2GB** EeePC Surf*, I have no more space left!

This is quite normal, and it happens every now and then. Just delete a few large, unneeded files and everything should be good, right?

So I go and find a **2MB** file in /tmp, and `rm -rf` it. Check free space again, and -- still nothing?!

I had to remove about **30MB** of files before it registered some free space.

Now, my question is, what's up with this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do the “Used” and “Available” columns of `df` output add up to the figure in the total column? (The output of `df` reflects the data from the underlying `statvfs` system call, so you'll find the same numbers in any other application.)

If not (which is probably the case), that's because by default, on an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem, 5% of the space is reserved to root. This space is not included in the “Available” column. So if you've filled exactly 95% of the filesystem, the available space is 0.

You can change the user who gets the 5%, or change the amount (all the way to 0 if you like), with `tune2fs` (options `-g` and -u`to control who gets it,`-m`or`-r` to control how much there is).

Comment: Good answer, but beware that the filesystem reserves this space for root for a good reason.  If system daemons can't write to the disk, bad things can happen.  If an interactive user can't write to disk, there's a good chance they'll be able to cope without data loss.

Comment: To add to Warren's comment about reserved space: when space goes below a few percent, the filesystem tends to fragment like crazy, because it's sticking bits of files wherever it can find the space. There's a performance cost to keeping your drives that close to full.

Comment: @p-static: I think (but I could be wrong) that there won't be much of a performance hit on an SSD. (There are certainly no moving heads in an SSD, but I don't know if scattered writes have a performance impact; it might depend on the type of SSD.)

Comment: There is a hit, it's just much less severe. You don't have any physical latency from moving parts, but fragmentation on a SSD still means issuing a lot of small requests for data instead of one large one.

Comment: this space is also important to avoid fragmentation

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's possible to have multiple hard-links to the same file, and removing one link does not cause the file to be deleted. Although this is unlikely to apply on /tmp.