# 129 MB used space shown in the SD card even after formatting it with mkfs.ext4

Tags: linux, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ext4: How to account for the filesystem space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/ext4-how-to-account-for-the-filesystem-space)

The full 2 GB space doesn't get shown as free space even after fully formatting it with **mkfs.ext4**. Are these some system files which have occupied the space of 129 MB?

Comment: @Giles So this means that 129 MB are used for the file system storage?

Comment: Yes, 128 MB is for the journal, then usually there is a bit more for the resize inode.

Comment: @psusi The inodes take up more room than the journal. @Anisha You can see an example calculation in the post I've linked. Try running `tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1` (or whatever the device is), and checking if the calculation works out. Also make sure you're interpreting the output of `df` correctly, if that's what you're looking at (see also [What happened to my free space](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2827/what-happened-to-my-free-space)).

Comment: @Gilles yes, but the inode tables are not counted as "used space".