# ext4 inodes in use for files that are missing

Tags: ext4

Executive summary:

- Every tool I've tried confirms lots of inodes in use on this ext4 partition
- Every tool I've tried shows me that there are no files on the partition
- It's not [files held open](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34140/tell-fs-to-free-space-from-deleted-files-now) and it's not an [overlay mount](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145429)

Long story:

I have an SSD with a single ext4 partition.  This drive was being used to continually store video from cameras, in short clips, and a cron job would periodically delete the oldest clips (in a C application, which deleted them by calling `remove()`).  After a while someone noticed that while there should have been about 5 days' worth of video backed up, there was hardly any, but the drive was almost full.

I took a look and naively tried just removing `lost+found`, but the drive was still full.  So, I deleted *everything* (`rm -rf *`), but `df -i` tells me that 91230 inodes are in use, even though `ls` and `du` show nothing at all.

`e2fsck -fv` found no errors to fix (aside from creating `lost+found` again), and `dumpe2fs` and `tune2fs -l` both agree with `df -i` on the number of used inodes.  I've tried `e2fsck -b` with a couple of the backup super-blocks and it didn't seem to make any difference.

`baobab` shows the same used space as `df` in the summary view, but when I click on the partition to see where the space is used, it only shows the 4.1kB used by  the empty `lost+found` directory.

The problem is *not* that deleted file handles that are still open - nothing is open.  I've mounted and unmounted this partition multiple times, and even taken the drive out and put it in a completely different machine.

I know I could just re-format the partition and start fresh, but I would really like to understand what's going on here and whether there's any "proper" way to fix this - I don't care whether it brings the files for those inodes back or it makes them properly deleted so they don't use up all the space.

Edit:
Running `dump` creates a backup file roughly equal in size to the used space reported by `df` et al.  Then running `restore` to a different drive created a chain of directories that's clearly wrong (`/media/usb0/20150426/10/1_20150426_100125.264/20150426/10/1_20150426_100125.264/` and it continues many levels deep, the same structure repeating), before printing a bunch of lines like:

```
expected next file 7823361, got 7610674
expected next file 7823361, got 7610675
```

(second number incrementing - it goes back well beyond my terminal's buffer) before finally:

```
cannot find directory inode 11
abort? [yn]
```

Choosing `n` results in more "cannot find directory node x", so I aborted.

Giving up and writing this off as a freak file-system corruption which hopefully won't happen again.

Comment: Sadly, `debugfs` has no way of listing inodes on a device ([however it does appear "easy to implement"](http://lists.openwall.net/linux-ext4/2011/08/17/8)). The "solution" there was to call `stat` on every possible inode number, to check whether it is used, and if so, for which entry. `debug2fs`'s `icheck` command could also help you check block-by-block instead. Also note that formatting is a rather "proper" way to handle this situation, since it does exactly what you want: reset the inode tables.

Comment: Did you run `fsck` **after** recreating `lost+found` with `mklost+found`?

Comment: Can the [dump](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dump) command find anything?

Comment: @Gilles yes, multiple times to no avail.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Well it did _something_.. Edited answer with my results.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Fair point re. formatting, but I was hoping it would be possible to fix the faulty inodes without affecting any remaining valid data on the disk, in case this were to happen again.

Comment: It is not formatting (we don't have to do that any more (unless you use floppies). It is re-creating the file-system. Formatting is the process of dividing a medium into blocks. Most media, these days, have controllers that do this for you. Microsoft still calls this formatting, because their disk formatter, would format then create a file-system, and they have not moved on to the future.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Commenting on a 3 year-old question for some tangential pedantry :D
I _would_ up-vote if it weren't for that unmatched parenthesis...